# FastAPI SQLAlchemy - How to Encrypt Table Column and then Decrypt when Querying Result?

Tags: python, encryption, sqlalchemy, cryptography, fastapi

I have a table called `users`. I want to encrypt the `phone_number` column in the SQL table, and then decrypt `phone_number` when querying the `users` table and returning a User item.

Here's an example:

**models.py**

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    phone_number = Column(StringEncryptedType(String(255), settings.ENCRYPT_KEY), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
```

**schemas.py**

```
class UserResult(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[uuid.UUID]
    username: str
    phone_number: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UsersResult(BaseModel):
    people: List[UserResult]
```

**users.py**

```
async def db_get_users(db: AsyncSession) -> List[Users]:
    result = await db.execute(select(Users))
    return result.scalars().all()


async def db_create_user(db: AsyncSession, user: UserResult) -> Users:
    instance = Users(**user.dict())
    db.add(instance)
    await db.commit()
    return instance

@router.get("/users", name="users")
async def get_all_users(
    request: Request,
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session),
    # authenticated: bool = Depends(check_authentication_header),
):
    request.app.logger.info("Retrieving list of all users ...")

    return {"users": await db_get_users(db)}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error when hitting the `/users` endpoint for getting a list of all users in the SQL table:

```
starlit-fastapi-app |     decrypted_value = self.engine.decrypt(value)
starlit-fastapi-app |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 121, in decrypt
starlit-fastapi-app |     decrypted = base64.b64decode(value)
starlit-fastapi-app |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
starlit-fastapi-app |     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
starlit-fastapi-app | binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringEncryptedType` base64-encodes encrypted values before writing them to the database. The error message tells us that a value read from the encrypted column cannot be decoded from base64. The most likely cause is that the column contains values that are not encrypted, perhaps because they were inserted directly, or the column was migrated from an unencrypted type and the existing values were not encrypted.

If this explanation is correct we can fix the data by reading it out as text, filtering out encrypted rows and writing the unencrypted rows back to the database through SQLAlchemy.

To identify unencrypted rows, we can use a function like this:

```py
import base64
import binascii

def is_base64(value):
    try:
        base64.b64decode(value['phone_number'])
    except binascii.Error:
        return False
    return True
```

(If your phone numbers are strings composed entirely of digits you could use `str.isdigit` as a filter. You could also use a compiled regex if they all share a consistent format.)

Now we can read, filter and update:

```py
import itertools
import sqlalchemy as sa

with engine.begin() as conn:
    tbl = Users.__table__
    # Extract the value of id and phone_number for each row.
    # Cast phone_number to String so that SQLA doesn't try to
    # decrypt it.
    # SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to like "id" in the bindparams, so
    # we give it an alias. 
    values = conn.execute(
        sa.select(
            tbl.c.id.label('uid'), sa.cast(tbl.c.phone_number, sa.String)
        )
    )
   
    # Filter out rows can that can be base64-decoded, on the assumption 
    # they are encrypted.
    updates = list(itertools.filterfalse(is_base64, values.mappings()))

    # Write the values back to the table, encrypting them automatically.
    stmt = (
        sa.update(tbl)
        .where(tbl.c.id == sa.bindparam('uid'))
        .values(phone_number=sa.bindparam('phone_number'))
    )
    conn.execute(stmt, updates)
```